# How to have a master detail datatableview/gird in django

Tags: django, datatable, master-detail

I'm developing an application with many tables and my users need to see data as grids and do some operations such add,edit, export , .. . To achieve this, I use [django-datatable-view](https://django-datatable-view.readthedocs.io/en/latest/);

I'd like to have a master-detail datatableview in my app. I've used MultipleDatatableView according to the [document](https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-datatable-view/blob/master/demo_app/example_app/views.py#L1124).

I'm confused How to edit the front and add a GET parameter hint (exp: ?datatable=master) . Without using MultipleDatatableView, my code works correctly but when I change it to multiple, it doen't work because of this error:

```
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'datatable'
```

I tried to add datatable=master in the option of datatable, but this doesn't work.

The reason I'm using datatableview is that I need a custom library to show complex data in a table with many features such formatter function, exporting , .... If there is better ways in django, I would be delighted to know.